# PhoneGap - Geolocation Error

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I have an issue that seems extremely straight forward but I cannot understand where I am going wrong!

I am using PhoneGap (2.9 build) to obtain Geolocation data. The following function (getGeolocationData) is being called on initialization. The issue is with location services conditions...

1. If location services is on upon application start up, geolocation
   data is obtained. (OK)
2. If location services is off upon application start up, an error is
   displayed and the geolocation function s called again. (OK)
3. If location services is on upon application start up, geolocation data is obtained, but during usage if I disable location services, no error is given!! (ERROR).

Note: When location services are turned off, the alert message 'geoGeo called' is no longer called.

Can anyone help me with this annoying issue?

Thanks in advance!

Ryan

```
function getGeolocationData() {
    alert("getGeo called.");
        var options = { maximumAge: 7000, timeout: 7000, enableHighAccuracy: true }; 
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        }

            // onSuccess Geolocation
            function onSuccess(position) {
                lng = position.coords.longitude;
                lat = position.coords.latitude;
                acc = position.coords.accuracy;            
                alt = position.coords.altitude;                
                hdg = position.coords.heading;               
                spd = position.coords.speed;                 


                geo_flag = 1;  //obtained geolocation? 1 = Yes / 0 = No
                document.getElementById("geo-status").innerHTML = 'On';
                alert("success");

            }

            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            function onError(error) {
                document.getElementById("tracking-status").innerHTML = 'Off'; 
                document.getElementById("geo-status").innerHTML = 'Off'; 
                geo_flag = 0;  //obtained geolocation? 1 = Yes / 0 = No
                alert("failed");
                getGeolocationData();

            }
```

Comment: I have just been checking a couple of sites and it seems there is a flaw in phonegap's 2.9 release. I'll update version asap and post the results here. Thanks Ryan

Comment: Hi all, I just updated to phoneGap 3.5.0 and the error still persists! Seems ill need to find a work-around for this....

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're testing this on an iOS device because of turning on/off "location services"?

Seems like Phonegap is only checking the availability of location services when the watcher is added at app start-up time, not continuously on each update. Since you need to put your app in the background to reach Settings in order to disable location settings, you could try using the Phonegap resume event to clear/re-add the watcher and see if that results in Phonegap noticing that the state of location services has changed. Something like this:

```
var watchID;

function getGeolocationData() {
  alert("getGeo called.");
  var options = { maximumAge: 7000, timeout: 7000, enableHighAccuracy: true }; 
  if(watchID) navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
  watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
function onSuccess(position) {
  lng = position.coords.longitude;
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  acc = position.coords.accuracy;            
  alt = position.coords.altitude;                
  hdg = position.coords.heading;               
  spd = position.coords.speed;                 

  geo_flag = 1;  //obtained geolocation? 1 = Yes / 0 = No
  document.getElementById("geo-status").innerHTML = 'On';
  alert("success");

}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
function onError(error) {
  document.getElementById("tracking-status").innerHTML = 'Off'; 
  document.getElementById("geo-status").innerHTML = 'Off'; 
  geo_flag = 0;  //obtained geolocation? 1 = Yes / 0 = No
  alert("failed");
  getGeolocationData();
}

// Called on device being ready
function onDeviceReady(){
  getGeolocationData(); // start geolocation tracking
}

// Called on resuming app from background
function onResume(){
  alert("app resumed");
  getGeolocationData(); // reset geolocation tracking
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```